# Unable to get the value of first column from a row in dataset using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to iterate a dataframe using foreachpartition for inserting a value into database. I used foreachpartition and group the rows and using foreach to iterate each row. Please find my code below,

```
val endDF=spark.read.parquet(path).select("pc").filter(col("pc").isNotNull);

endDF.foreachpartition((partition: Iterator[Row]) =>
    class.forname(driver)
    val con=DriverManager.connection(jdbcurl,user,pwd)
      partition.grouped(100).foreach(batch => {
        val st=con.createStatement()
           batch.foreach(row => {
         val pc=row.get(0).toString()
         val in=s"""insert tshdim (pc) values(${pc})""".stripMargin
         st.addBatch(in)
      })
         st.executeLargeBatch
})
con.close()
})
```

When I try to get the pc value from the row(val pc=row.get(0).toString()) it's throwing the following exception. I'm doing this in spark-shell

> org.apache.spark.SparkException : Task not serializable . .

Caused by:

> Java.io.NotSerializable exception:
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataSet$RDDQueryExecution$ Serialization stack:
> Object not serializable
> (class:org.apache.spark.sql.DataSet$RDDQueryExecution$, value:
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataSet$RDDQueryExecution$@jfaf )
> -field(class:org.apache.spark.sql.DataSet, name:RDDQueryExecutionModule, type:
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataSet$RDDQueryExecution$)
> -object(class:org.apache.spark.sql.DataSet,[pc:String])

Comment: if you just want to insert the values why don't you use the dataframe write api directly instead of looping using foreachpartition?

Answer (score 0):

Function in `foreachpartition` need to be serialized and passed to executors.
So, in your case, spark is trying to serialize DriverManager class and everything for your jdbc connection, and some of that is not serializable.
foreachPartition works without DriverManager -

```
endDF.foreachPartition((partition: Iterator[Row]) => {
  partition.grouped(100).foreach(batch => {
    batch.foreach(row => {
      val pc=row.get(0)
      println(pc)
    })
  })
})
```

To save it in your DB, first do `.collect`

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The code which I mentioned in my question is working fine when I execute as a yarn job in Cluster.

Comment: Probably, in yarn cluster these classes were in classpath of executors.

Comment: Why do you call `class.forname(driver)` and what is `driver` value?